# Не работает autoplay у html5 video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Имеется видео на сайте:

```
<video id="hilton-video" width="1080px" height="1920px" autoplay loop>
<source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
```

Не работает атрибут `autoplay`,
Пробовал обойти:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("#hilton-video")[0].play();
        }, 60000);
});</script>
```

Не помогает, что делать?

Comment: Если не работает в хроме, то расслабиться и ничего не делать. Это новая политика хрома, теперь `autoplay` не будет работать при загрузке страницы. Видео начнет проигрываться только непосредственно от события пользователя.

Comment: Понял, спасибо, пока юзаю firefox, но в идеале хотел бы хром, может есть какой-то список исключений типо дверенных доменов где запускать автоплей. У меня тут просто панель на которой сайт и видео-заставка. на нее идет картинка с браузера моего компа